# Looping over forecast functions in tsCV

Tags: r, loops, time-series, forecast

I have a loop below looping over 4 time series forecast methods in `tsCV` (rolling forecast origin). The 3rd method in list, y, does not break the loop. However, the results table, z, whose purpose is to store MAE (mean absolute error) records `NaN` for this user defined function.

This forecast function is user defined as I need to specify `damped=T`

```
library(forecast)
x <- 8  # t +
y <- list(ses
          , holt
          , function(j, k){forecast(holt(j, h=k, damped=T))}, hw
          )
z <- list()

for (i in seq_along(y))
{
  a <- data.frame(tsCV(AirPassengers, y[[i]], h=x))
  a[1:12, ] <- NA  # 1st 12 months' forecast likely to be meaningless
  b <- colMeans(abs(a), na.rm=T)
  c <- data.frame(model = i
                  ,h = 1:x
                  ,mae = b
                  )
  z[[i]] <- c
}

z <- do.call(rbind, z)
z$model <- as.factor(z$model)
```

I got my idea for the user defined function here:
http://pkg.robjhyndman.com/forecast/reference/tsCV.html#see-also

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the documentation for `tsCV`, the supplied function needs to have an argument actually named "h". So just change your function to

```
y <- list(ses, holt, function(j, h){forecast(holt(j, h=h, damped=T))}, hw)
```

When you do that, no NaN values are returned.

Comment: You are correct. Referring to `?tsCV`, under `Usage` where we find:
`tsCV(y, forecastfunction, h = 1, window = NULL, xreg = NULL,
  initial = 0, ...)`
I was under the impression the `h` under `Arguments` was referring to the 3rd argument in `tsCV` not inside its counterpart in `forecastfunction`
Nonetheless, you provided the solution. Thank you.

Comment: I was more specifically referring to the "Arguments" section of the help pager where it describes the `forecastFunction` as "Function to return an object of class forecast. Its first argument must be a univariate time series, **and it must have an argument h for the forecast horizon**" (emphasis added). The `h` in the call to `tsCV` is technically a different variable.

Comment: Yes, I found that line (now). Thank you for spending your time to point it out. Teaches me to read guides thoroughly from now on.